# Sort JSON by time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have a function that gets JSON from an API (fetched with PHP). I can't figure out I'd sort the data by `payload.time`. The JSON is in random order, so `.reverse()` doesn't do any good ether. I'm wondering how is it possible to sort the following JSON in order by time?

```
{
   "code":0,
   "payload":[
      {
         "time":1349661897,
         "packages":[
            "49381"
         ],
         "ign":"player1",
         "price":"15.99",
         "currency":"USD"
      },
      {
         "time":1354504024,
         "packages":[
            "33109"
         ],
         "ign":"player2",
         "price":"6.99",
         "currency":"USD"
      }
}
```

Here's my JS:

```
var Donors = function(api) {

   this.list = api;

   $.each(this.list.payload.slice(0, 25), function(i, donor) {
     var ign = donor.ign,
       price = donor.price,
       currency = donor.currency,
       el = '<li id="' + ign + '" class="player big" data-player="' + ign + '" title="'+ ign + ' // ' + price + ' ' + currency + '">☺</li>';
      if(price !== "-") $('#donors').append(el);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function to sort JSON array :

```
function sortBy(jsonArray, key){
    if(jsonArray){
       var sortedArray = jsonArray.sort(function(left, right) { 
                         //array.sort is buit-in function
           var a = left[key];
           var b = right[key];
           if (a !== b) {
               if (a > b || a === void 0) return 1;
               if (a < b || b === void 0) return -1;
           }
           return 0;
      });
      return sortedArray;
    }
}
```

call this function with :

```
sortBy(payload, 'time')
```

**Note:** Code snippet is not tested.

Comment: Would the jsonArray be what's passed in api param?and the key would be payload.time?

Comment: You have to call `sortBy(this.list.payload,'time')` in your case.

Comment: I can't figure out where id' put this in my function. Before the $.each() or after. I tried both, and it did not sort.

Comment: Added [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdkanani/ywrLr/).
You have to pass result `sortedArray` in $.each function instead of `this.list.payload`

Comment: It's `Array.prototype.sort`, not `Array.sort` :-)